# Is there a way to pull trending instagram hashtags in real-time?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, hashtag

I'm working on an app that would automatically generate instagram hashtags for the user, allowing them to snap a photo, get auto hashtags, and post right away. Is there a way I can pull the most trending instagram hashtags in real-time and have the app generate them for every user at the time they're posting?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no direct way to get this information from the API. Though you might be able to get clever with the [endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) that are there and figure out what's trending that way.

You could query a user using the users endpoint, search through all the hashtags they've used on the last 100 or so media captions, and then infer "trendy" hashtags that way.

You could query a hashtag using the hashtags endpoint, search through all the hashtags used on the last 100 or so media captions, and then infer "trendy" hashtags that way.

One thing that I do in my app (https://app.promoplanner.net) is I look at the frequency of posts for a given hashtag (i.e. what's the average time between each post for a given hashtag). Small time deltas tell me that a hashtag is popular.

Either way, you need to start your query with either a user or a hashtag, you can't as a broad question like what's trending. You can only ask questions like "what's  trending relative to @kesha" or "what's trending relative to #urbanfarming"

Comment: Thanks Mike! That helps!